# Lodash: how to find max and min values of each id

Tags: lodash

My data array is

```
array = [{id: 2, name: "kent", status_id: 2, date_1: "2018-08-09", date_2: "2018-07-06"},{id: 2, name: "kent", status_id: 10, date_1: "2018-01-09", date_2: "2018-09-06"},{id: 3, name: "tracy", status_id: 2, date_1: "2018-05-03", date_2: "2018-10-02"},{id: 3, name: "tracy", status_id: 2, date_1: "2018-01-10", date_2: "2018-09-12"},{id: 3, name: "tracy", status_id: 10, date_1: "2018-02-10", date_2: "2018-09-02"},{id: 4, name: "lucy", status_id: 10, date_1: "2018-12-10", date_2: "2018-08-09"},{id: 5, name: "steve", status_id: 10, date_1: "2018-12-7", date_2: "2018-04-01"}]
```

If the id =2 I would like to find max(date_1) & min(date_2) for each id=2. Like my output should be,

```
id
2    max(date_1)   min(date_2)
3    max(date_1)   min(date_2)
4    max(date_1)   min(date_2)
5    max(date_1)   min(date_2)
```

I am using Lodash library. I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `groupBy` **id** and then **map** each grouped values using `mapValues` since that will be a object. while mapping the grouped values you can use `_.maxBy` and `_minBy` to find *max and min*

```js
var array = [{"id":2,"name":"kent","status_id":2,"date_1":"2018-08-09","date_2":"2018-07-06"},{"id":2,"name":"kent","status_id":10,"date_1":"2018-01-09","date_2":"2018-09-06"},{"id":3,"name":"tracy","status_id":2,"date_1":"2018-05-03","date_2":"2018-10-02"},{"id":3,"name":"tracy","status_id":2,"date_1":"2018-01-10","date_2":"2018-09-12"},{"id":3,"name":"tracy","status_id":10,"date_1":"2018-02-10","date_2":"2018-09-02"},{"id":4,"name":"lucy","status_id":10,"date_1":"2018-12-10","date_2":"2018-08-09"},{"id":5,"name":"steve","status_id":10,"date_1":"2018-12-7","date_2":"2018-04-01"}]
var res = 
  _(array)
  .groupBy('id')
  .mapValues(a => ({
    max: _.maxBy(a, 'date_1').date_1,
    min: _.minBy(a, 'date_2').date_2
  })).value();
  
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi ... @koushikChatterjee , how should I map id also along with date_1 & date_2?

Comment: use `id: a.id`, like max, min key

Comment: I have tried that earlier but the output comes as undefined for all dates and I also tried for a.name which results in the undefined output. @koushikChatterjee

Comment: Yeah, because its an array. So you have max, min, now you want id,name of which one (for every gruop) ? Because every group contains multiple records

Comment: makes sense ... thanks I tried using _.maxBy(a,'name').name & _.maxBy(a,'id').id which shows output as ID, Name, Date_1, Date_2 :)

Comment: Yeah, You got it :)

Comment: as you already grouped by `id` you can use `a[0].id` directly as they all have same value, no need to evaluate `max` of them